# How can I generate the .ear of my project using Jenkins + Ant?

Tags: jenkins, jakarta-ee, ant, devops, ear

I am learning Jenkins an I am able to build a project using Ant. I can't understand one thing, when I build a project using Netbeans and Ant I get the **.ear** in a **dist** fodler but one I build the same project uisng Jenkins and Ant I dont get the **.ear** (no **dist** folder too!).

To build a project (entreprise application built with Ant) using Jenkins I followed the following steps:

- I have created a new job in jenkins (freestyle job)
- In the Build section I added a new `build setup` (Invoke Ant)
- In the Invoke Ant section, for `Targets` I have put `compile` and for `Build File` I have put `build.xml`
- Then I copied the content of my project in the created folder by Jenkins in the workspace
- Finally I started the build.

How can I generate the **.ear** of my project using Jenkins + Ant?

Here is the content of my `build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for -->
<!-- some examples of how to customize the build. -->
<!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) -->
<!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. -->
<!-- Commands such as Run, Debug, and Test only use this build script if -->
<!-- the Compile on Save feature is turned off for the project. -->
<!-- You can turn off the Compile on Save (or Deploy on Save) setting -->
<!-- in the project's Project Properties dialog box.-->
<project name="SIFC" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:ear="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2ee-earproject/2">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project SIFC.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <!--

    There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
    used for execution of your tasks. These targets are usually executed 
    before and after some main targets. They are: 

      pre-init:                 called before initialization of project properties 
      post-init:                called after initialization of project properties 
      pre-compile:              called before javac compilation 
      post-compile:             called after javac compilation 
      pre-dist:                 called before archive building 
      post-dist:                called after archive building 
      post-clean:               called after cleaning build products 
      pre-run-deploy:           called before deploying
      post-run-deploy:          called after deploying

    Example of pluging an obfuscator after the compilation could look like 

        <target name="post-compile">
            <obfuscate>
                <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            </obfuscate>
        </target>

    For list of available properties check the imported 
    nbproject/build-impl.xml file. 


    Other way how to customize the build is by overriding existing main targets.
    The target of interest are: 

      do-dist:                archive building
      run:                    execution of project 

    Example of overriding the target for project execution could look like 

        <target name="run" depends="<PROJNAME>-impl.jar">
            <exec dir="bin" executable="launcher.exe">
                <arg file="${dist.jar}"/>
            </exec>
        </target>

    Notice that overridden target depends on jar target and not only on 
    compile target as regular run target does. Again, for list of available 
    properties which you can use check the target you are overriding in 
    nbproject/build-impl.xml file. 

    -->
</project>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use Ant? Maybe it's easier generate ear using Maven.

Comment: @Lorelorelore in our company we have old projects (built with Ant)  that are still running and we consider using Jenkins so yes I need to generate ear using Ant  :)

Comment: Probably give some more background infos on that, eg. How is your command line look like, when invoking the ant build? Is there a difference between Jenkins invokation and your local build? What's your jenkins build environment look like? Any log messages from the jenkins build?

Comment: Knowing your project's structure could be helpful, it is difficult to give you advice without having this information.

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach I did not post any code because I thought I am asking a basic question, I thought that generating an ear from a project is an easy task :)

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach as for your question `Is there a difference between Jenkins invokation and your local build?` in fact this question is similar to my question  =)

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach and for this question `Any log messages from the jenkins build?` the log shows `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` I am able to build the project and I get a folder named `build` that contains the **.war** and the **ejb.jar** of my project. But no **.ear** file.

Comment: Let's keep this brief: The '.ear' file may be build by some disinct task in your ant build file. I'm asking about the command invokations from your local build and your Jenkins build to see if there are differences.

Comment: @Lorelorelore Is there a standard way to generate the **.ear** using Jenkins + Ant?

Comment: I can't tell because I am not an Ant expert. I guess that you can reproduce Maven's way of composing ear files in Ant.

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach I edited my question please check it.

Comment: Maybe see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778039/how-to-package-an-ejb-as-an-ear-from-netbeans). You probably need to add 'dist-ear' to the Targets of the Invoke Ant section.